# Terraform For Loop To Generate JSON From Map

Tags: terraform

Looking for the easiest way in terraform to create a JSON string (preferably using jsonencode) or something similar i've looked at the few examples on the terraform docs but still struggling to nail the exact formatting to get this output right. This should make it pretty easy to keep the dev.env file we use in our docker-compose to transfer nicely into this large array that's used in several of our containers.

```
locals {
  container_envs = {
    ENV = "dev"
    CONTAINER_TAG = "dev"
  }
}
```

To the following type of output

```
[{
  "name": "ENV",
  "value": "dev"
},
{
  "name": "CONTAINER_TAG",
  "value": "dev"
}
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the following should work (not sure if the order is important or not):

```
locals {
  container_envs = {
    ENV = "dev"
    CONTAINER_TAG = "dev"
  }
}

output "test" {
  value = [for k,v in local.container_envs: { name = k, value = v }]
}
```

which gives:

```
test = [
  {
    "name" = "CONTAINER_TAG"
    "value" = "dev"
  },
  {
    "name" = "ENV"
    "value" = "dev"
  },
]
```

Comment: You're a wizard! That's worked perfectly, much appreciated!